# jQuery return first 5 words of a string without commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I'm trying to return the first 5 words of a string in a readable format, no "" or commas separating words. I'm not sure if its a regex thing or what, but I can't figure it out although its probably simple. Thanks!

See what I have thus far:
http://jsfiddle.net/ccnokes/GktTd/

This is the function I'm using:

```
function getWords(string){
    var words = string.split(/\s+/).slice(1,5);
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is a `join()`

Try this:

```
function getWords(str) {
    return str.split(/\s+/).slice(0,5).join(" ");
}
```

This will do something like:

```
var str = "This is a long string with more than 5 words.";
console.log(getWords(str)); // << outputs "This is a long string"
```

Take a look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) for a further explanation of the `.join()`. function in javascript. Essentially - if you don't supply an argument, it uses the default delimiter `,`, whereas if you supply one (as I'm doing in the above example, by providing `" "` - it will use that instead. This is why the output becomes the first 5 words, separated by a space between each.

Comment: I had to use .slice(0,5) or it chopped off the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Those commas are coming from how you output the data:

```
//write to DOM
$('<h2 />').text(getWords(str).join(' ')).appendTo('body');
```

​
When you add a string to `getWords(str)`, javascript tries to convert the array into a string - it does this by joining the words with commas. If you want to join them with something else, use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Answer (score 0):

Troy Alford solution is working, but is has one drawback. If between words there will be more than one space, or new line character (\n) it will be converted to single space, e.g:

'jQuery is a
multi-browser'

will be converted to

'jQuery is a multi-browser'

To fix this issue, we might use word boundary regex. It might looks like this:

```
function getFirstWords(text, wordsAmount) {
  const arr = text.split(/\b/g);
  const arrItemsAmount = (/\b/.exec(text) && /\b/.exec(text).index) ?
                           wordsAmount * 2 :
                           wordsAmount * 2 - 1;
  return arr.slice(0, arrItemsAmount).join('');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with str.substring(1,15)

Comment: I'm afraid this does not really answer the question